# How to receive result as "keyBy" of an object instead of array from mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

lodash has a function named keyby
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy
how to get result like that?

```
const data = db.collection.find()


[
    { id: 'a', text: 'text' },
    { id: 'b', text: 'text' },
    { id: 'c', text: 'text' },
    { id: 'd', text: 'text' },
    { id: 'e', text: 'text' },
]

lodash.keyBy(data, 'id')

{
    a: { id: 'a', text: 'text' },
    b: { id: 'b', text: 'text' },
    c: { id: 'c', text: 'text' },
    d: { id: 'd', text: 'text' },
    e: { id: 'e', text: 'text' },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the object in find query in MongoDB.
But, you can build one by using lodash 'keyBy'

```
const data = db.collection.find({}, function(err,results){
     if(err) throw err;
       return lodash.keyBy(results, 'id');
});
```

Comment: so aggregation framework can't do that ? i have to pull the records first then keyby it

Comment: @crapthings yes